# Extracting attributes from XML file using xmllint

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xmllint

This is a part of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<nlpcmp>
 <word string="getuserscount" occurrences="2">
  <systems>
   <system name="mks">
    <pos file="IrcChannel.cpp" part="adjective" line="414" occ="2"/>
   </system>
  </systems>
 </word>
 <word string="setuserprivilege" occurrences="2" >
  <systems>
   <system name="mks">
    <pos file="IrcChannel.cpp" part="adjective" line="375" occ="2"/>
   </system>
  </systems>
 </word>
 <word string="hasprivilege" occurrences="2" >
  <systems>
   <system name="mks">
    <pos file="IrcChannel.cpp" part="verb" line="360" occ="2"/>
   </system>
  </systems>
 </word>
 <word string="partmessage" occurrences="2" >
  <systems>
   <system name="TEST">
    <pos file="IrcChannel.cpp" part="verb" line="308" occ="2"/>
   </system>
  </systems>
 </word>
</nlpcmp>
```

I am trying to find the list of the strings for the systems that is called mks only using xmllint

The output should give me:

```
getuserscount
setuserprivilege
hasprivilege
```

so I tried this command:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//nlpcmp/word/@name)' file.xml
```

and there was no output, then I tried:

```
xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='word'][system/@name[mks]" file.xml
```

and it says : 
XPath error : Invalid predicate
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed

Then I tried

```
xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='word']" file.xml
```

and it gave me all the contents of the "word" tag, which I do not want. I only need the strings. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This xmllint command

```
xmllint --xpath "/nlpcmp/word[systems/system/@name = 'mks']/@string" file.xml
```

will yield this output

```
getuserscount
setuserprivilege
hasprivilege
```

as requested.